# Function Pointer using "typedef" keyword with Function Address stored as Variable? (C++ 14, VS 2019)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, templates

**Problem Summary**

I'm attempting to create a callable function pointer inside of a function using templates for its return value and its arguments using C++ 14. I want the callable function pointer to return the templated type, and accept templated arguments. However, I also want the callable function pointer to point to an existing function at the address provided in an argument as an integer. This I am unsure of how to do. Below is an illustration of my current incomplete code:

```
template <class retTempl, class argTempl_1, class argTempl_2>
retTempl TEST_1(argTempl_1 value1, argTempl_2 value2, int addr) {

    typedef retTempl(*TEST_2)(argTempl_1, argTempl_2);
    return TEST_2(value1, value2);

}
```

In this case, `TEST_2` is the new function pointer that I want to call, and the `addr` argument is the address of an existing function that I want the `TEST_2` pointer to point to.

The current error that the VS 2019 compiler throws at me is the following:

```
Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'operationFunction'
```

I am unsure of exactly what it's trying to tell me, researching this error online leads to several possible causes, not all of which necessarily have to do with function pointers. However, this error may not even be relevant, as I have not been able to implement the function address yet. That is mostly what I want to focus on here.

**My Attempts**

I know that in order to make a function pointer created with the `typedef` keyword point to an actual function, you need to set the pointer variable equal to whichever function you want the pointer to point to. So for instance (example from https://www.section.io/engineering-education/function-pointers-in-c++/):

```
int add(int x ,int y)  
{  
    return x + y;  
}  
int main()  
{  
 int (*funcptr)(int, int);
 funcpointr = add;

 ...
}
```

However, here the function that I want the `TEST_2` pointer to point to is different every time that `TEST_1` is called, with a different return value and arguments. Therefore, I cannot simply set the `TEST_2` variable equal to the `addr` argument:

```
template <class retTempl, class argTempl_1, class argTempl_2>
retTempl TEST_1(argTempl_1 value1, argTempl_2 value2, int addr) {

    typedef retTempl(*TEST_2)(argTempl_1, argTempl_2);
    TEST_2 = addr;
    return TEST_2(value1, value2);

}
```

as this now supplies me with an additional VS error:

```
Error   C2513   'retTempl (__cdecl *)(argTempl_1,argTempl_2)': no variable declared before '='
```

I would assume that I would require another pointer variable here, perhaps from a list of function pointers that I want the `TEST_2` variable to point to, but at this point I would like to hear a second opinion before I resume.

Is what I'm trying to achieve here even possible to do with C++? Is there a different way that this should be done that I'm not aware of?

Thank you in advance for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: `typedef` declares a type, not a variable.  If you want a variable you need `TEST_2 variable_name = value;`

Comment: `TEST_2` is a type, not a pointer (not an object of pointer type). You probably meant something like `reinterpret_cast<TEST_2>(addr)(value1, value2)`

Comment: `TEST_2` isn't a variable.  It is a type.  An alias for `retTempl(*)(argTempl_1, argTempl_2)` (pointer to a function returning `retTempl` and accepting two arguments of type `argTempl_1` and `argTempl_2`).  If you need an object of that type you need to create one.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you for your response;
So, what would "value" be in my case here? What would I need to do in order to call the function?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for your response;
So how would I create the function pointer object, with the address variable? Do I just typecast it after the reinterpret_cast command?

Comment: @MilesBudnek thank you for your response;
So how would I call that function, with that object created? What would the syntax be?

Comment: @Runsva The same way you call any function via pointer: `TEST_2 test2 = some_function; test2(arg1, arg2);`

Comment: @MilesBudnek thank you so much, I am getting somewhere! Just one more step, is there a way now to use the "addr" int variable that holds the address of the function in memory, to make the "test2" pointer point to said function? Or do I explicitly have to give it the function name, every time?

Comment: @Runsva You could `reinterpret_cast` it (i.e. `TEST_2 test2 = reinterpret_cast<TEST_2>(addr)`), but you're relying on the fact that the address of a function _fits_ in an `int` (it doesn't on x86_64, for example).  You're _probably_ safe if you use a `void*` instead of an `int` (function pointers fit in a `void*` on most modern platforms), but its not a guarantee.  It would help if you said _why_ you want to do this; there may be a better way.

Comment: @MilesBudnek thank you for your response;
I actually found out that I could simply just cast as such "TEST_2 test2 = (TEST_2)(addr)", and the code works as intended. I also got some other good answers from cplusplus.com, and I will be posting my findings here soon as a reply to my original post, however before that I wanted ask you;
Since the pointer wouldn't fit in all cases into an "int" variable, would they fit into a "uintptr_t" type? I heard that this type was specifically created for pointers.

Comment: @MilesBudnek also, the reason I'm doing this is because I'm trying to write a scripting language interpreter. This specifically is just a way to define operation functions for a variety of operators, hence why I'd want a function pointer that can point to a variety of different functions. If there is a better way to do this, please do let me know !

Comment: @Runsva Perhaps you want `std::any`?  That will at least give you runtime checking to make sure you retrieve the same type you stored.  `uintptr_t` will work similarly to `void*` in this case.  Neither is guaranteed to be able to hold function pointer types by the language spec, but they both can on all modern systems I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, and posting this question on other programming forums, I reached an answer, and several other conclusions that I believe are worth sharing in regards to my original problem (very informative answers provided to me on this forum: https://cplusplus.com/forum/general/284539/).

**Immediate Solution**

The immediate issue in my original code was the fact that I mistakenly assumed that the `typedef` keyword creates an object, instead of an object type. What should have been done was to create an object instance of the type created with the `typedef` keyword (huge thanks to the people in the comments of my original post here for pointing this out). So:

```
TEST_2 test_function;
```

Following the creation of the object instance with the type of the function pointer, I have the argument `addr` of type `int` that holds the address of the function I want the `TEST_2` pointer variable to point to. While the use of variables of size `int` isn't the best way to store function addresses (as `int` isn't large enough to store all formats of function addresses, and could result in other issues with the pointer), if you are forced to retrieve your function from an `int` variable, then you would need to typecast the address variable to your function pointer type in the variable you have created. So:

```
TEST_2 test_function = (TEST_2)(addr);
```

or

```
TEST_2 test_function = reinterpret_cast<TEST_2>(addr);
```

So the whole original function being:

```
template <class retTempl, class argTempl_1, class argTempl_2>
retTempl TEST_1(argTempl_1 value1, argTempl_2 value2, int addr) {

    typedef retTempl(*TEST_2)(argTempl_1, argTempl_2);
    TEST_2 test_function = (TEST_2)(addr);
    return test_function(value1, value2);

}
```

This now worked on my end to call my desired function, and to return the correct variable and type. However...

**Proper Solution**

As stated previously, using a variable of size `int` is not ideal for storing function addresses. There is a variable type designed to store addresses, `uintptr_t`, however this type of variable is only designed to store *object* addresses, not function ones.

The proper way to do this would be to always store your function pointers exclusively as pointer types, such as `void(*)()`, to avoid any discrepancies with the function addresses. If there really is a need to store function addresses in variables, then it would be ideal to use `memcpy`, instead of casting, to achieve this (although I have not experimented with this as of now).

Thank you to everyone who helped me out with this issue!